# How to remove separator in date?

Tags: php, html, date

how to remove the separator from the date input I have below

```
$date=$_POST["input"];
$new = date_format($date,"Y M D");
```

Comment: what is input date string?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<?php 

$date=$_POST["input"];

// prints the current time in date format  
echo date("Y M D", strtotime($date))."\n"; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use date_create() to change datatype from string to date

```
$date=date_create($_POST["input"];);
echo date_format($date,"Y M D");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` function convert date string into unix timestamp. Then convert into required format.

```
<?php 
    echo date("Y M D", strtotime($_POST["input"])); 
?>
```